# Highest image quality and upload

Tags: image, image-processing, image-resizing, image-gallery

I am building an image gallery website that allows photographers to upload high quality images (typically taken with a DSLR) to their own image gallery.

1. Is there any limit on the maximum file size a user can upload on my website?
2. During the uploading process, how can we maximize and preserve its quality?
3. What's the best way to display the images at their full quality? (For eg. should images be placed as a background image of a div, or as img src ?)

Comment: Maximize and preserve quality by storing the file exactly as the user provided it, bit-for-bit. Any attempt to sanitize or compress the file has the potential to lose something.

Comment: @MarkRansom yes, but how do we do that exactly? I'm referring to steps we can take to ensure the file is uncompressed. does move_uploaded_files() automatically compress anything?

Comment: I think your question is far too broad. Is it related to image processing? web server? Which language are you talking about? I don't know.   Please create a small but complete example with an image, code etc that someone can reproduce. See ([mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you are asking generally, then this is off topic.